# How can I use a generator of JPEG images and convert it into a video stream?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, video-streaming

I am trying to setup a website to access a security camera from the outside world. However, it only has one image per refresh, and it's a JPEG. However, I am not sure what the best approach is.

I have tried taking the JPEG and putting it into a generator, and then passing that into `StreamingHttpResponse`. However on mobile it stops after a while, and I don't know how to easily apply `HTML/CSS` to it to make it look nice. The code below is my `StreamingHttpResponse` solution,  but again, it doesn't work too well.

```py
def content_gen(url):
    while True:
        res = requests.get("{}/top.htm".format(url), allow_redirects=True)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        image = "{}/{}".format(
            url,
            soup.html.body.table.find_all('tr')[4].td.table.tr.img['src']
        )
        byte_resp = requests.get(image)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + byte_resp.content + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

I am not exactly sure what to do, I don't know how to integrate AJAX with this which is what I've seen suggested. If possible, I would like to see an example just to see it materialized better.

Comment: Does it only stop on mobile and works fine on desktop?

Comment: @xyres Yeah, is that just the nature of StreamingHttpResponse? I wanted to find a way around that just because it's annoying to refresh it when it stops, and I'm not sure how to embed it in HTML to make it look nice.